# Recriar div estilo do goole

Tags: html, css, div

preciso recriar essa div como mostra a imagem[image: div a ser recriada]

essa parte onde fica a letra do nome do usuário já foi criado, é basicamente posicionar o nome, e-mail e o botão de mudar conta.

o código até agora:

```
<div class="conta">
    <p>Você está logado com:</p>
    <div class="perfil">{{name}}</div>
    <div class="dadosUser">
        <p>{{user.username}}</p>
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>  
        <a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" class="btn btn-dark">Mudar de Conta</a>
    </div>
</div>

.conta{
    border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Talvez meu código o ajude.

```css
.main{
    font-family: arial;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
}
.button{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.dados{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#main-title{
    color: gray;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#perfil{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#user{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#email{
    color: gray;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <div id="main-title">
        <p> Você fez login como</p>
    </div>

    <div id="perfil">
    <p>E</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dados">
    <p id="user">Epamer</p>
    <p id="email">epamer8880@gmail.com</p>
    </div>

    <a href="#" target="_blanck "class="button"> Mudar de conta </a>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).